# Is it bad practice to export a default function filled with functions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm new to es6 modules and I feel like I'm probably doing this in a way that's considered bad practice. Here's a general idea to how I've been approaching it:

app.js

```
import head from './head';
head();
```

head.js

```
const eyes = () => {
}
const nose = () => {
}
const mouth = () => {
}

export default function() {
   eyes();
   nose();
   mouth();
}
```

Comment: I've done it in the past; it's non standard because normally you would return an object, even with a single function inside, but I couldn't find a satisfactory reason why not. I'm sure our friends here can provide more insights ;)

Comment: I'm no expert but personally I don't think it's bad practice, don't know if it's even something that ties into es6 specifically because people use such exports with es5 too. Even the express npm module technically exports a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it bad practice to export a default function filled with functions?

**No, it is not a bad practice.**  There's nothing wrong with what exporting a function that calls a bunch of other functions.  You are just exporting a single function.  If that single function chooses to do its work by calling a bunch of other functions, that's all perfectly fine.

Keep in mind that the concept of `export` is just a means of sharing functions or data from one module to another.  You're just exporting a function.  How that function is implemented (whether it calls other functions or not) has absolutely nothing to do with the export or with ES6 or with modules.  If it's an appropriate internal design for that function to call other functions of yours to do its job, then that's perfectly fine and really has nothing to do with the fact that it was exported.

By not exporting the functions `eyes`, `nose` and `mouth` you are just making them private to your module (so they can only be called from within your module) which is a perfectly fine design decision if they are intended to be private to your module or if they are simply not needed elsewhere.